# Input field with icon

Tags: vmware-clarity

How do I get an icon before the input field in clarity ui? [image: something like the image below] something like the image above.

Answer (score 1):

I have done an example in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v1-0-scuboe). You can check it and feedback me if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the internal forms demo for Clarity that has an example of a search box that has the icons like you want. This is intended to eventually be made possible with the Angular form components as well.

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/dev/src/app/forms/input-group/input-group.html#L75